# Underscore naming convention regex

Tags: regex, naming-conventions

What is the regex for variables using underscore naming convention?

- starts with a letter
- list of words (in which you can use numbers) separated by underscores
- everything is lower case

For the sake of research, I will remind first that the naming conventions are a very important part of programming. There is a [lot of debate](http://code-cruising.net/underscore-vs-camelcase-naming-convention) about them, even [here on SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-ab).

As for my specific use case, I wanted to use an XSD validation for a process described in XML. As this would be imported into a database where some fields would be used as keys, I wanted to restrict the naming to the classic "underscore separated" naming convention.

I was surprised to find out the question has rarely been asked. The only reference I could find on it was a description in a software designed to [check coding style](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html) written for Java.

The closest thing to what I wanted was

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I was looking for this kind of regex and didn't find one here, so I added it.

Comment: The hover-text says: `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`, which might be the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I beg to disagree here. This is a legitimate question when you're trying to validate naming conventions, as the tags suggest. The answer is not overly complex, but it isn't obvious either. I thought this was the purpose of this site to share knowledge, am I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry for my initial comment; it was too hostile. Hmm, I am also not sure if this is proper knowledge sharing. The problem posted is very, very specific. The next question might be "CamelCase naming convention regex", then "camelBack naming convention regex", then "LISP-hyphened naming convention regex", then "ALL-UPPERCASE naming convention regex", "space separated naming convention regex" and so forth. Then "German Phone Number regex", pick any.

Comment: No, you are not mistaken. Knowledge sharing is the whole purpose of this site. However, it puts some restrictions on the style and content of the questions and answers.

Comment: Hm. Though it is specific indeed, it isn't AS specific as your examples seem to be. Even though, if the question was indeed camelCase naming convention regex, wouldn't it be a legitimate question aswell, considering that almost all "generic" questions have already been answered here and only details remain now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50856/discussion-between-kethryweryn-and-phresnel)

Comment: Yes, it is very specific (I would say just as specific as my other examples). But then it is so specific that I think it would require to state what exactly the problem is (which does not apply to you here). I think I don't find a 100% opinion right now; maybe we just wait how the others decide :)

Comment: I'll edit and add a few other things, it will probably make things clearer. ;)

Comment: This looks somewhat better; sorry about the chat, have been in a meeting :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using :

```
[a-z][a-z0-9]*(_[a-z0-9]+)*
```

Note that the same pattern can be used for CONSTANTS_NAMING_CONVENTION by simply replacing the a-z parts by A-Z.